# Is it possible for a Scheduled Task to run as NETWORK SERVICE?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-xp, scheduled-task

It is quite simple to set up a task to run as a SYSTEM, but when setting it to NETWORK SERVICE it show "Access is denied" error message.

Is there any way to get this working? (The problem is that I don't want to create a new domain user for that task and I need to access a remote share from this task.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[I asked this same question](https://serverfault.com/questions/512056/how-to-run-a-scheduled-task-as-networkservice-in-windows-server-2003). Fortunately RyanRies was able to provide a [correct answer](https://serverfault.com/a/512061).

In Windows Server 2003 you **cannot** run a scheduled task as `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` (aka the [Network Service account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). That capability only was added with Task Scheduler 2.0, which only exists in Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008.

Bonus Chatter

- [**LocalService** Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684188(v=vs.85).aspx) is a built-in account with limited privileges on the local computer, and accesses the network as *anonymous*. You should use this account to run your scheduled tasks
- [**NetworkService** Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx) is a built-in account with limited privileges on the local computer, and accesses the network as the machine (e.g. `VADER$`). You can use this account to run your scheduled tasks if you need authenticated network access
- [**LocalSystem** Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx) is a built-in account with extensive privileges on the local computer. You should **never** use this account to run scheduled tasks

Answer (score 7):

You can't. The functionality was introduced in Task Scheduler 2.0, which means Vista/2008+.

From the documentation for Schtasks.exe:

> /RU username
>
> A value that specifies the user context under which the
>   task runs. For the system account, valid values are "", "NT
>   AUTHORITY\SYSTEM", or "SYSTEM". For Task Scheduler 2.0 tasks, "NT
>   AUTHORITY\LOCALSERVICE", and "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE" are also
>   valid values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx:

Comment: It's very helpful that the doc's **specifically** mention Task Scheduler 2.0. It eliminates the guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

I tried doing this several ways, but now I don't think it's possible. I'd be glad to stand corrected on this, but I tried everything I could think of, including adding `NETWORK SERVICE` to `Administrators`, tweaking all sorts of Local Security Policy settings, etc.

When I enable auditing, I get this:

```
Event Type:     Failure Audit
Event Source:   Security
Event Category: Account Logon 
Event ID:       680
Date:           02/03/2010
Time:           8:49:53 PM
User:           NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Computer:       RESULTANT
Description:
Logon attempt by: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
 Logon account:  NETWORK SERVICE
 Source Workstation: RESULTANT
 Error Code: 0xC0000064

Event Type:     Failure Audit
Event Source:   Security
Event Category: Logon/Logoff 
Event ID:       529
Date:           02/03/2010
Time:           8:49:53 PM
User:           NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Computer:       RESULTANT
Description:
Logon Failure:
     Reason:        Unknown user name or bad password
     User Name:     NETWORK SERVICE
     Domain:        NT AUTHORITY
     Logon Type:    4
     Logon Process: Advapi  
     Authentication Package: Negotiate
     Workstation Name:       RESULTANT
```

`0xC0000064` decodes to `NO_SUCH_USER`. That's a bit silly, considering that I entered only `network service` – how did it know that the account that failed was in `NT AUTHORITY`?

When I enter an invalid username, I don't even see the authentication attempt at all. So clearly *something* agrees that `NETWORK SERVICE` is an actual account.

If I botch the password for a known username (ie `Administrator`), I get `0xC000006A` (`STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD`).

---

Try adding the `Log on as a batch job` right to `NETWORK SERVICE`. I think it's a silly idea; you should just bite the bullet and create a domain account…

Comment: Sorry I mistyped in my previous comment to Matt, but I tried adding it for "Log on as a batch job" and with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "Log on as a service" right to the network service account. Detailed instructions [here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Nope. It was already listed in "Log on as a service", and adding to "Log on as a service" didn't helped too.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to revive this thread as it **IS** possible to use NETWORK SERVICE for tasks!
At the least on both Server 2016 and 2019!

Just a little oddity after selecting the account the usual way.
Under

```
Run whether user is logged on or not
```

You confusingly have to select:

```
Do not store the password. The task will only have access to local computer resources
```

The second part of that should be taken with a shovel full of salt! As what it means here is that you do not have *credentials*, but if you run something that do not need the account to have credentials, it DOES have access to the network!

Exporting a job, the principal part looks like this

```
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-20</UserId>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
```

I use it for sending status mails through smtp, and it contact the smtp-server just fine

Answer (score -1):

Network Service is a local (computer) account. It will therefore never have rights on another computer (where the share resides).

If you want access to a networked share you have to use an account that is known in the network, so use a domainaccount. And the service you want to run MUST support UNC addressing. If it needs network drive letter access, you need a user session with mapped drives, other wise this also will fail.

(I suppose you know this already, looking at the date of your post. My answer is just an extra for people who wil find this post with a similar issue)

Kees

Comment: Each computer joined to the domain have its own account in the Active Directory. And as far as I understand `NETWORK SERVICE` is a local alias to that account therefore it could potentially have access to some shares.

Comment: NetworkService *will* have rights on another computer. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx): *" It has minimum privileges on the local computer and acts as the computer on the network."*

Comment: This answer is incorrect. As @IanBoyd also says, NETWORK SERVICE is specifically intended for accessing items on the network (that's why it has "Network" in the name, by contrast with the LOCAL SERVICE account) which it will access using the computer's domain identity, DOMAIN\COMPUTERNAME$, e.g., MAIN\WEBSRV2$.

Comment: It's also not an account (local or otherwise).  It's a well-known security principal.