# How to run a Scheduled Task as NetworkService in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task

How do i configure a scheduled task to run as [`NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272.aspx) in Windows Server 2003?

### Background

Even though the account is known as `NetworkService`, the full name is `NT AUTHORITY\Network Service`.

On Windows Server 2008 R2, when choosing the account to run the task as, you **must** specify:

- `NETWORK SERVICE` (with a space)

That will then resolve to `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` (no space):

[image]

**Note**: You **cannot** try to specify **`NetworkService`**

[image]

Nor can you specify **`NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService`**.

In summary:

- `NETWORK SERVICE` *valid*
- `NetworkService`  ***invalid***
- `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` ***invalid***

The same is true on Windows 7. You **must** specify `NETWORK SERVICE` if you wish for a scheduled task to run as `NetworkService` (aka `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService`)

### What about Windows Server 2003?

In Windows Server 2003 it doesn't work:

[image]

i know that any password given for the `Network Service` (or `Local Service`) accounts are ignored, as the accounts have no password:

> Note that this account does not have a password, so any password information that you provide in this call is ignored.

But i cannot specify that account:

[image]

- `NETWORK SERVICE` *invalid*
- `NetworkService` *invalid*
- `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` *invalid*

### NetworkService security

The `NetworkService` account, like `LocalService`, are limited rights accounts. The only difference between them is that:

- **NetworkService** presents machine credentials (e.g. **VADER$**) when accessing the network
- **LocalService** presents anonymous credentials when accessing the network

My question works just as well if i want to have a scheduled task run as `LocalService` (aka `NT AUTHORITY\LocalService`). i just happened to choose **NetworkService** when asking this question.

See the question:

> [How to grant network access to LocalSystem account](https://serverfault.com/questions/135867/howt-to-grant-network-access-to-localsystem-account)?

How do i configure a scheduled task to run as `NT AUTHORITY\Network Service` in Windows Server 2003?

## Bonus Reading

- [MSDN: NetworkService Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684272.aspx)
- [MSDN: LocalService Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684188.aspx)